# What is Apache Velocity?

Tags: java, apache, velocity

Can someone please explain, what is Apache Velocity ?
what is its purpose ?

It would be nice to provide an example along with it.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Come on. The [Apache Velocity Engine web site](http://velocity.apache.org/engine/releases/velocity-1.7/index.html) (I think, you speak about the engine) contains everything. An overview with a nice explanation, a user guide with an example, and much more.

Comment: You just used a tag that has quite a lot of information on the subject in its very description :) Click the [tag:velocity] label in your question to read it.

Comment: Was unable to grasp it clearly. Have less experience about these. That's why posted. Thanks anyway.

Comment: The reason for closing this question is doubtful. As shown, the question can be answered concisely enough.

Answer (score 30, accepted):

Apache Velocity is a [template engine](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Template_processor). That means that you can add variables to a context, load a template in which those variables are referenced and render a text from this template where the references to the variables are replaced with the variable's actual value.

It's purpose is to separate design and static content from code. Take a website for example. You don't want to create HTML inside your java code, do you? You would have to recompile your app every time you change a bit of design and you would polute your code with unnecessary design clutter. You would rather want to get your variables, either computed or from a database or whatever and have a designer create a HTML template in which your variables are used.

Some pseudo code to make it clear:

```
/* The user's name is "Foo" and he is of type "admin"*/
User user = getUserFromDatabase("Foo");

/* You would not add hard coded content in real world.
 * it is just to show how template engines work */
String message = "Hello,";

Velocity.init(); /* Initialises the Velocity engine */

VelocityContext ctx = new VelocityContext();

/* the user object will be available under the name "user" in the template*/
ctx.put("user",user); 
/* message as "welcome" */
ctx.put("welcome",message);

StringWriter writer = new StringWriter();

Velocity.mergeTemplate("myTemplate.vm", ctx, writer);

System.out.println(writer);
```

Now given a file called myTemplate.vm

```
${welcome} ${user.name}!
You are an ${user.type}.
```

The output would be:

```
Hello, Foo!
You are an admin.
```

Now let's assume the flat text should be HTML instead. The designer would change myTemplate.vm to

```
<html>
<body>
  <h1>${welcome} ${user.name}</h1>
  <p>You are an ${user.type}</p>
</body>
</html>
```

So the output would be a html page *without* a single change in the java code.

So the use of a template engines like Velocity (there are others, e.g. [Thymeleaf](http://www.thymeleaf.org) or [Freemarker](http://freemarker.org)) let designers do a designer's job and programmers do a programmer's job with minimal interference to each other.

Comment: Got it to the point. Thanks for being precise and answering all questions.

Comment: Thanks. Very clear.

Comment: Best answer. Thanks